# Is there a Magento 2 Membership Extension that offers functionality similar to Amazon Prime Membership?

Tags: magento2

I have a **grocery store** built upon **Magento 2**. I am looking for a way to incorporate membership functionality that will allow the grocery stores' premium customers to buy products at a discounted rate. (Think of Amazon Prime Membership where Prime members pay an annual fee and enjoy benefits like faster shipping, reduced product prices etc.)

Is there an extension that offers this exact functionality? I have come across a couple of extensions but found out they offer only membership "plans" functionality not what I am looking for.

Answer (score 0):

Please find some modules which do satisfy your requirements such as membership, product discounts/rules, shipping discount/rules.

https://landofcoder.com/magento-2-membership-extension.html

https://www.magedelight.com/membership-subscription-magento-2.html

https://marketplace.magento.com/magenest-membership.html

Go through the demo of these modules to see if it actually satisfies your needs.

Comment: Thanks for your resources, Raj.

I have already checked the demos of first and second extensions you've referred and found out they do not satisfy the exact need, however, I will check out the third one.

Comment: Whether does any one of the module suits all your needs?